# TiKz for each iteration over spaced string argument has an extra }

Tags: tikz-pgf, xstring

This is an example of the functionality of a macro, that should the following: iterate over a spaced string and print the first letter of each part.

```
\newcommand\text{\StrSubstitute{a b c}{ }{,}}
\foreach \i in \text{
     \StrLeft{\i}{1} ,
}
```

But apparently, I cannot use `\StrLeft` or any other when the iteration is over something I have done over a StrSubstitute. Why is that?
Error messages:

```
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.<to be read again>\par }
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.<to be read again>\par }
! Missing control sequence inserted.<inserted text>\inaccessible }
```

The following do work though:

```
\newcommand\text{\StrSubstitute{a b c}{ }{,}}
\foreach \i in \text{
    \i
}

\newcommand\text{a,b,c}
\foreach \i in \text{
     \StrLeft{\i}{1} ,
}
```

Comment: `\text` is not `a,b,c`, but the set of instructions necessary to produce `a,b,c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the choice of `\text` as a command name is not really good, because `amsmath` uses it. However, this is not the main point.

The big problem is that `\text` is *not* the list `a,b,c`, but rather a set of instructions for producing that list.

You're luckier with

```
\StrSubstitute{a b c}{ }{,}[\mytext]
\foreach\i in \mytext{%
  \StrLeft{\i}{1}, %
}
```

Now `\mytext` contains the result of the substitution.

Full example, although it's not clear what's the use case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute{a b c}{ }{,}[\mytext]

\foreach\i in \mytext{%
  \StrLeft{\i}{1}, %
}

\end{document}
```